# How to pass socket variable while using exec() in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a program version A that calls execve() to execute another program version B while retaining the same PID.

This program A has a socket object and we would like the other program B to access the same socket to send some data to the established connection.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to successfully recover the serialized socket, I'm saving it to a file, opening the file again in the new program B but it is not the same object, is uninitialized and doesn't have any attributes set, I have used dill and pickle.

Is there a safe way to pass variable objects while calling exec()? Or a way to get the pointer reference of the object and pass that pointer forward?

Version A:

```
#!/bin/env python
import os
import dill as pickle
import socket

print "Version A"
print os.getpid()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("127.0.0.1",80))

with open('file1.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(s, handle)

os.execlp('python', 'python', 'verB.py')
```

Version B:

```
#!/bin/env python
import os,pdb,sys
import dill as pickle
import socket

print "Version B"
print os.getpid()
infile = open('file1.pickle','rb')
infile.seek(0, 0)
s = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()

s.send("mymessage")

s.close()
```

Version B socket `s` is uninitialized, how to recover the socket?

Comment: Python *doesn't have pointers*. Why are you using `exec`? You should design your other program to be importable, that is the sanest way of accomplish this. Then you can just do `import other_program; whatever_we_need = other_program.main()`

Comment: Internally it has pointers to some objects, copying a list into a variable is actually a pointer to that list, not a copy of the list.

Comment: No. **Python doesn't have pointers**. You are describing implementation details of CPython, that are neither here nor there, because **python the language doesn't have pointers**.  If you disagree, show me how to use a pointer, dereference a pointer, do some pointer arithmetic. I think you'll find you can't. And you don't copy lists into variables. That isn't the semantics of Python.

Comment: I have a socket that needs to retain the ESTABLISHED state between programs, I'm forbidden to initiate a new socket.

Comment: ... right, so again, *why don't you use the one program as a module*, then state is shared automatically. It is with exec as well. So it isn't exactly clear the *exact* issue you are running in to. It would help if you gave an example.

Comment: We are updating the program from version A to version B while retaining open connections, we need to pass the same socket to the new version.

Comment: I do not have access to the same variables when version B is running, I have access to argv[] but serializing the socket for argv doesn't work, I get an empty new socket when I do that.

Comment: The socket is still alive as netstat output indicates when version B is running, and it points to the correct PID, is just that I can't find a way to use it.

Comment: I need to use exec() in order to maintain the PID, otherwise my sockets will close if I close the program to run a new version.

Comment: I have updated the question to add the reproducible example.

Comment: it wasn't copied, I added it to Version A

Comment: You can't pass the socket to the exec'd process; but you can pass the fd number, and then open it with `socket.socket(fileno=number)`. Probably, if python's `exec` does not close fds from the parent when called.

Comment: Thanks @vanza That worked, please post your comment as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: Aha! See, this is critical, why you need to provide a [mcve]. You kept saying `exec` so I assumed you meant the built-in `exec`. Yes, as @vanza says, you can pass the fileno arg, and `os.exec*` shouldn't close it.

Comment: @vanza a related [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/#backward-compatibility) regarding the inheritance of file descriptors.

Comment: @felartu feel free to accept the answer, don't wait for mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unix-like systems `execve` programs retain open file descriptors that are not marked `FD_CLOEXEC`. You need to pass the file descriptor (a small integer) to the new process. Python sets file descriptors to close-on-exec by default, so if your parent is a python process, it needs to specifically change that flag. You can write the socket fd to a file:

```
open("file1.txt", "w").write(str(s.fileno()))
```

but more commonly, one would either pass it on the command line or tuck it into the environment. As an example of python calling python with the socket passed on the command line:

verA.py

```
import socket
import os
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("stackoverflow.com", 80))
os.set_inheritable(sock.fileno(), True)
os.execlp(sys.executable, "python", "verB.py", str(sock.fileno()))
```

verB.py

```
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.fromfd(int(sys.argv[1]), socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n")
print(sock.recv(500))
```